# Where to begin creating a Powershell script for this?

Tags: powershell, x509certificate

If I needed to give a certificate an additional permission as described below, where do I even begin with in Powershell? There must be a Windows commandline executable that I have to start with from commandline. Only then I could think about writing it in a powershell script, correct?

> 1. Click Start, type mmc in the Search programs and files box, and then press ENTER.
> 2. On the File menu, click Add/Remove Snap-in.
> 3. Under Available snap-ins, double-click Certificates.
> 4. Select Computer account, and then click Next.
> 5. Click Local computer, and then click Finish. Click OK.
> 6. Under Console Root, Certificates (Local Computer), in the Personal store, click Certificates.
> 7. Right-click xxAzurehost1 certificate that has been created earlier. Choose All Tasks > Manage Private Keys. Click Add and then Advanced.
>      Click Locations and choose your local computer. Click Find Now. Select
>      NETWORK SERVICE in the search results and click OK. Click OK. In the
>      Permissions for xxxazurehost1 private keys window, select NETWORK
>      SERVICE and give Read permissions. Click OK.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To control the ACL for the private key all you have to do is edit a file ACL. The trick is to find which file.

Private keys are stored in:

```
%ProgramData%\Microsoft\Crypto
```

On XP:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\Microsoft\Crypto
```

Under here you'll see keys organized by algorithm e.g. DSS, RSA.

The User Store will be subfolder with a user SID. The Local Machine store will be in subfolder:

```
MachineKeys
```

Here's a way to get the file which stores the private key information for your cert.

1. First go into the local machine personal certificate store:

   ```
   PS> cd cert:\LocalMachine\My
   ```
2. Now you have to get a handle to your cert. There's more than one way to do this, here's one using the thumbprint:

   ```
   $cert = dir | ? {$_.Thumbprint -eq "232820EEBF7DBFA01EE68A28BA0450671F862AE1"}
   ```
3. Now you can find the private key file name like this:

   ```
   $fileName = $cert.PrivateKey.CspKeyContainerInfo.UniqueKeyContainerName
   $keyFile = dir -Path "C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\Microsoft\Crypto" -Recurse | ? {$_.Name -eq $fileName}
   ```
4. $keyFile will be the FileInfo object you can change the ACL on with either Set-ACL or icacls.exe

Comment: Thank you very much for this. It gave me the right direction and I also have found a blog that did exactly this http://tinyurl.com/cbsmpqk . As it seems you do understand exactly what I am trying to achieve, which role would you give permission to read the private key without compromising the security of the website? I have given it to Users and it works, just wondering if that means only Users on the machine can read it or anybody from Internet and what the consequences are. Thanks

Comment: Always follow the rule of least permissive. I take it you were getting an error without modifying the ACL. You should be able to determine exactly what account is trying to access the private by using procmon while initiating your app. Since you know what the private key file path is, review the procmon log for ACCESS DENIED and check the properties to see what account it is. I'm guessing it would be the application pool identity.